# JQuery change functions for select boxes. Only running first function

Tags: jquery, select

I am trying to get two change functions to run, one when one select box is changed, the other when another select box is changed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#area").change(function() { 
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "./includes/AJAX/getFunctions.cfm?areaID=" + $(this).val(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#functions").html(html)
                    }
                }); //end of AJAX call
        }); //end of area

        $("#function").change(function() {
            alert("Change"); 
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "./includes/AJAX/getDefects.cfm?functionID=" + $(this).val() + "&areaID=" + $("#area").val(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#defects").html(html)
                    }
                }
                );
        }); 
    });
```

I am only able to get the first function to run, but the second never does. I use firebug to just make sure there is not an error in syntax, but it never reaches the code. Anyone have any ideas what is happening?

Here are my select boxes in my html:

```
 <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Business Area:
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <cfselect name="area" id="area">
                            <option value="">Select Business Area</option>
                        <cfloop query="getAreas">
                            <option value="#getAreas.areaID#">#getAreas.areaDesc#</option>
                        </cfloop>
                            </cfselect>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--- Business Function --->
                    <tr id="trFunction" style="display:none">
                        <td align="right">
                            Business Function:
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                        <div id="functions">
                            <select name="functionID" id="functionID">
                                <option value="">Select Business Function</option>
                            </select>
                         </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--- Defect Type --->
                    <tr id="trDefect" style="display:none">
                        <td align="right">
                            Defect Type:
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                        <div id="defects">
                            <select name="defect" id="defect">
                                <option value="">Select Defect</option>
                            </select>
                         </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

And here are the queries:

```
<cfquery name="getFunctions" datasource=#application.datasource#>     
    SELECT *
    FROM lamFunctions
    WHERE status = 1
    AND areaID = '#url.areaID#'
    ORDER BY functionDescription        
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
    <select name="functionID" id="functionID">
        <option value="">Select Business Function</option>
    <cfloop query="getFunctions">
        <option id="#functionID#" name="#functionDescription#" value="#functionID#">#functionDescription#</option>
    </cfloop>
    </select>   
</cfoutput>

<cfquery name="getDefects" datasource=#application.datasource#>     
    SELECT *
    FROM lamDefects
    WHERE status = 1
    AND areaID = '#url.areaID#'
    AND functionID like '%#url.functionID#%'
    ORDER BY defectDesc        
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
    <cfif #url.functionID# eq 3>
        <select name="defect" id="defect" style="width:350px">
            <option value="">Select Defect</option>
        <cfloop query="getDefects">
            <option id="#defectID#" name="#defectDesc#" value="#defectID#">#defectDesc#</option>
        </cfloop>
        </select>
    <cfelse>
        <select name="defect" id="defect">
            <option value="">Select Defect</option>
        <cfloop query="getDefects">
            <option id="#defectID#" name="#defectDesc#" value="#defectID#">#defectDesc#</option>
        </cfloop>
        </select>
    </cfif>    
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Looks pretty good at first glance... what's your HTML?

Comment: The obvious thing is `#function` compared to `#functions`. Is this deliberate?

Comment: #functions is a div, function is a select box.

Comment: is function (the select box) inside of the div#functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that I see is that you are calling second change function on $("#function") whereas the Id of your second select statement is functionID. Second thing is that event handlers registered in document.ready function only apply to elements that are already loaded on the page. for elements that are added later you can use

```
$("#functionID").live('change', function(){
//handle event
});
```

but using change event with live caused some problems for me on different browsers (IE especially). so another option could be using livequery library of jQuery or you can register the event handler on callback of your first ajax request like

```
$("#area").change(function() { 
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "./includes/AJAX/getFunctions.cfm?areaID=" + $(this).val(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#functions").html(html)
                        $("#functionID").change(function(){
                            //handle event here                       
                         });
                    }
                }); //end of AJAX call
```

Comment: Nice! That worked. I appreciate your help! (Sorry, I am very new to JQuery, and don't always know how everything works.)

Comment: @shawleigh i would suggest trying Pointy's answer as well. delegates are new things and may offer some benefits over traditional way.

Comment: Basically, anything you can do with ".live()" you can do with ".delegate()", but the opposite is not true.  The main advantages to ".delegate()" are that it's more efficient to establish the handlers, and it allows the "bubble point" to be situated anywhere in the DOM (".live()" always puts handlers on the `<body>` tag).

Comment: FYI live is now deprecated, you should use `$("#functionID").on('change', function(){ });` now

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. The `<select>` in the "functions" `<div>` is called "functionID", not "function"
2. Because the ajax call is dropping new stuff into "functions", you should use ".delegate" to establish the event handler:

   ```
   $('#functions').delegate('#function', 'change', function() {
     // your event handler here
   });
   ```

By using ".delegate()", you hook up the actual event handler to the `<div>`, and it'll get the "change" events from the enclosed `<select>` (whose "id" had better be "function") and run the handler.  Because you're never destroying the "functions" `<div>` the handler will keep working no matter how many times the first ajax call runs.

Comment: does using delgate has any problems in terms of browser compatibility? Putting it another way; any cautions when using delegate?

Comment: No, making ".delegate()" (and the related ".live()" - I prefer ".delegate()") work properly across all major browsers is core jQuery functionality.

Comment: +1 i encountered few problems when using live with change event of select list. is there something to it or i should review the code i had written? what i found on the net is that some change event is propogatable on some browsers and non-propogatable on others.

Comment: Well there can be some issues, but I *think* that "change" from `<select>` should bubble reliably. Are you seeing some actual problems?

Comment: yes i did have problems when using change with live function and i had to take a detour. let me check again if problem continues i will post it in separate question and let you know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a select with id=function, yours is called functionID

Comment: Sorry, i had made some changes after posting this, and posted the update afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Change this selector:

```
$("#function")
```

To this:

```
$("#functionID")
```

Comment: I did, but it didn't help. I figured it could have something to do with function being reserved.

Comment: It shouldn't, but you most definitely need to give them the same name.  If you're going to stick with functionID in your html, then make sure your jquery says functionID